# Matlab: optimize code

Tags: matlab, optimization

Problem:
I have the trajectories of 14 users: I have compare the trajectories of every user and for each one, I have calculated the longest common sequence: TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString. Now I want to compare the longest common sequence of the first user with the others, the longest common sequence of the second user with the others and etc.

I have no problems to compare the longest common sequence of two users using this code:

```
string3=TrajSimilarity(1,3).aLongestString;
string4=TrajSimilarity(1,4).aLongestString;
[D,dist,aLongestString]=LCS(string3,string4);

U=numel(regexp(string3,'(\(\d+\)|\d)'));
V=numel(regexp(string4,'(\(\d+\)|\d)'));
nLCS=numel(regexp(aLongestString,'(\(\d+\)|\d)'));

ratioU=nLCS/U;
ratioV=nLCS/V;

EA = (ratioU + ratioV)/2;
WA = (U*ratioU+V*ratioV)/(U+V);
```

LCS is a function that calculates the longest common substring between two strings (if can be helpful, I will post a link with it). 
I have problems to create an optimized code that compare the longest common sequence of the first user with the others, the longest common sequence of the second user with the others and etc.
I try this code:

```
for k=1:14
   string3=TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString;
    for j=2:14
        string4=TrajSimilarity(1,j).aLongestString;
        [A(j,k).D,A(j,k).dist,A(j,k).aLongestString]=LCS(string3,string4);
    end
end
```

but it generates error:

```
Attempted to access L(0,0); index must be a positive integer or
logical.

Error in LCS (line 52)
dist = L(n,m);
```

Can you give me an help? thanks

Comment: Try to print out some debug information, or use the debugger to single step through the code. I guess some of your strings are empty? Note also that you, except for k=1, that you compare each with itself ( 2 and 2, 3 and 3, etc.)

Comment: you have reason: there are empty strings that generate errors; I have correct the code eliminate them and It works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
% Similarity between two users
for k=1:14
    % string3 e string4 must be > 1
    string3=TrajSimilarity(1,k).aLongestString;
    for j=2:14
        string4=TrajSimilarity(1,j).aLongestString;
        % entrambe le variabili temporanee devono essere non vuote per
        % poter essere confrontate
        if (~isempty(string3))&&(~isempty(string4))
            % calculate distance and a longest string
            [A(j,k).D,A(j,k).dist,A(j,k).aLongestString]=LCS(string3,string4);

            U=numel(regexp(string3,'(\(\d+\)|\d)'));
            V=numel(regexp(string4,'(\(\d+\)|\d)'));
            A(j,k).nLCS=numel(regexp(A(j,k).aLongestString,'(\(\d+\)|\d)'));

            A(j,k).ratioU=A(j,k).nLCS/U;
            A(j,k).ratioV=A(j,k).nLCS/V;

            A(j,k).EA = (A(j,k).ratioU + A(j,k).ratioV)/2;
            A(j,k).WA = (U*A(j,k).ratioU+V*A(j,k).ratioV)/(U+V);

        end
    end
end
```

The code works only if string3 and string4 are >1 and it doesn't generate errors.

Comment: It is nice that you found a solution; you can accept your own answer, I guess. Note that for k=2, j=2 you have string3==string4, and likewise for k=3,4..14

Comment: yes, I know. I'm looking for a solution: I hope to solve it!

Comment: If you want to skip equal string indices, you simply check if `j` is different from `k` before you do your comparison.

Comment: E.g. `if (~isempty(string3))&&(~isempty(string4)) && j~=k`